# Automatically updating a page with new images in Symfony and PHP using Ajax and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to make a page that displays the images of my frames and display them one by one during the duration defined beforehand. I want my page to update automatically without reloading when I add new images.

I have this ajax request that reloads the page every minute but I want it to be done automatically.

**The Controller :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Chanel;
use App\Repository\ChanelRepository;
use DateTime;
use DateTimeImmutable;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ChanelController extends AbstractController
{
    
    #[Route('/chanels', name: 'app_chanel')]
    public function index(ChanelRepository $repository): Response
    {
        $chanels = $repository->findBy([], ['name' => 'ASC']);

        return $this->render('chanel/index.html.twig', [
            'chanels' => $chanels,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/chanel/{id}', name: 'app_chanel_show', requirements: ['id' => "\d+"]
    ,
        methods: ['GET']
    )]
    public function show(Chanel $chanel): Response
    {
        $frames = $chanel->getFrames();
        $currentDateTime = new DateTime();
        $activeFrames = [];
        $frameDurations = [];
    
        foreach ($frames as $frame) {
            $frameStartDate = $frame->getDateDeb();
            $frameEndDate = $frame->getDateFin();
    
            if ($currentDateTime >= $frameStartDate && $currentDateTime <= $frameEndDate && $frame->isIsPublic()) {
                $activeFrames[] = $frame;
                $frameDurations[] = $frame->getDuration();
            }
        }
    
        return $this->render('chanel/show.html.twig', [
            'chanel' => $chanel,
            'frames' => $activeFrames,
            'frameDurations' => $frameDurations,
        ]);
    }
    


    #[Route('/chanel/{id}/frames', name: 'app_chanel_frames', requirements: ['id' => "\d+"]
    ,
        methods: ['GET']
    )]
    public function frames(Chanel $chanel): JsonResponse
    {
        $frames = $chanel->getFrames();
        $activeFrames = [];
        $frameDurations = [];
        $currentDateTime = new DateTime();

        foreach ($frames as $frame) {
            $frameStartDate = $frame->getDateDeb();
            $frameEndDate = $frame->getDateFin();

            if ($currentDateTime >= $frameStartDate && $currentDateTime <= $frameEndDate) {
                $activeFrames[] = $frame;
                $frameDurations[] = $frame->getDuration();
            }
        }
        $data = [
            'frames' => $activeFrames,
            'frameDurations' => $frameDurations,
        ];

        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
}
```

**The view**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Chanel {{ chanel.id }}{% endblock %}

{% block header %}{% endblock %}

{% block head %}

    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('css/chanel.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="{{ asset('css/footer.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endblock %}

    {% block javascripts %}

        <script>
            var frameDurations = JSON.parse('{{ frameDurations|json_encode|raw }}');
        </script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/image.js') }}"></script>
        <script>
            function charger(){
                setTimeout( function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url : '{{ path('app_chanel_frames', {id: chanel.id}) }}',
                        type : 'GET',
                        success : function(data){
                            if(data.success == false){
                                alert('erreur dans le rechargement')  
                            }else{
                                location.reload(true);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    charger(); // on relance la fonction

                }, 60000); // on exécute le chargement toutes les minutes

            }
            charger();
        </script>


    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="frame__images">
        {% for frame in frames %}
            {% if frame.isPublic %}
                {% for image in frame.frameImages %}
                    {% if frame.frameImages is null %}
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/icone.png') }}" alt>
                    {% else %}
                        <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(image, 'imageFile') | imagine_filter('resizing') }}" alt>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <footer>
        <h2>Ti Hebdo</h2>
    </footer>

{% endblock %}
```

**The javascript file that manages the image change**

```
console.log('Script en cours...');

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Récupérer toutes les images des frames
  var images = $('.frame__images img');
  
  // Masquer toutes les images sauf la première
  images.not(':first').hide();

  // Définir l'index de l'image courante
  var currentImageIndex = 0;

  // Fonction pour afficher l'image suivante
  function showNextImage() {
    // Masquer l'image courante
    images.eq(currentImageIndex).hide();

    // Incrémenter l'index de l'image courante
    currentImageIndex++;

    // Vérifier si on atteint la fin des images
    if (currentImageIndex >= images.length) {
      currentImageIndex = 0; // Revenir au début
    }

    // Afficher l'image suivante
    images.eq(currentImageIndex).show();
  }

  // Définir l'intervalle pour changer d'image en utilisant la durée de chaque frame
  var totalDuration = frameDurations.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0); // Calculer la durée totale des frames

  setInterval(showNextImage, totalDuration * 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this behavior, they are described in this article, for example: https://medium.com/geekculture/ajax-polling-vs-long-polling-vs-websockets-vs-server-sent-events-e0d65033c9ba.

But the problem is that there is no trivial way to subscribe to the database updates, so the best option you could achieve is just moving the polling process from client to server, which I believe makes no sense, because will just move load from client browser to your server.

So, maybe the implementation you have currently is the optimal one, in terms of complexity-to-benefits rate.